# Move directory via sftp in spring integration

Tags: java, spring-integration

I'm using spring integration to process a directory full of files. When I'm done, I'd like to move that directory to an archive folder. Is there any way to move a directory in spring integration?

```
<int-sftp:outbound-gateway session-factory="sftpClientFactory"
        request-channel="archiveChannel" command="mv -r" expression="payload" rename-expression="headers.destinationName" />
```

This didn't work, but I think would be analogous to what I am trying to do.

```
public boolean archiveNuggets(@Header("destinationName") String destinationName, String payload);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me. Only the difference that I use `mv` command. There is no that `mv -r` one. More over `mv` doesn't support `-R` option anyway.

See [Reference Manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-outbound-gateway) for more information.